# Return bool type from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Есть такая stored procedure и она ничего не возвращает, а я хочу чтоб она возвращала bool type.
если в таблице существует запись то должна возвращать true, а если нет то false

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [******].[****]
@GroupId BIGINT,
@EventId BIGINT
AS
    DECLARE @Exist BIT
BEGIN
if EXISTS(Select * From SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup s
    WHERE s.GroupId = @GroupId and s.EventId = @EventId)
BEGIN
    SET @Exist = 1
    RETURN (@Exist)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Exist = 0
    RETURN (@Exist)
END
END
GO
```

Comment: Может проблема в том, как вы вызываете эту процедуру?

Comment: а так все правильно тут написано?

Answer (score 0):

1-ый вариант:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [******].[****]
@GroupId BIGINT,
@EventId BIGINT,
@Exist BIT OUT
AS
    BEGIN
    if EXISTS(Select * From SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup s
        WHERE s.GroupId = @GroupId and s.EventId = @EventId)
    BEGIN
        SET @Exist = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Exist = 0;
    END
END
GO

-- Вызов процедуры.
DECLARE @GroupId BIGINT;
DECLARE @EventId BIGINT;
DECLARE @Exist BIT;
EXEC [******].[****] @GroupId, @EventId, @Exist OUT;
SELECT @Exist;
```

2-ой вариант:

```
-- Вызов процедуры.
CREATE PROCEDURE [******].[****]
@GroupId BIGINT,
@EventId BIGINT
AS
    --DECLARE @Exist BIT

    BEGIN
    if EXISTS(Select * From SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup s
        WHERE s.GroupId = @GroupId and s.EventId = @EventId)
    BEGIN
        SELECT [Exists] = CAST(1 AS BIT)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT [Exists] = CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END
END
GO

-- Вызов процедуры.
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Exists] BIT)
DECLARE @GroupId BIGINT;
DECLARE @EventId BIGINT;

INSERT INTO @T
EXEC [******].[****] @GroupId, @EventId;
SELECT * FROM @T
```

3-ий вариант:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [******].[****]
@GroupId BIGINT,
@EventId BIGINT
AS
    BEGIN
    if EXISTS(Select * From SimulatedResult.EventForSimulateGroup s
        WHERE s.GroupId = @GroupId and s.EventId = @EventId)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
END
GO

-- Вызов процедуры.
DECLARE @GroupId BIGINT;
DECLARE @EventId BIGINT;
DECLARE @Exists INT;

EXEC @Exists = [******].[****] @GroupId, @EventId;
SELECT CAST(@Exists AS BIT);
```